# Speed time distance calculations in google doc

Tags: time, google-docs

I am trying to calculate the time required to travel a certain distance at a specific speed in HH:MM:SS

[Check Doc here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AmZqKT8_r5b_dHBmSUt0eG1wWk9QZEVLUFNnamdHQXc&usp=sharing)

For some reason the values are incorrect, the decimal value is correct, but the time formatting is not working correctly.

What do i need to do to achieve my need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

divide your decimal number by 24, then format the cells as desired. [reference](http://www.addictivetips.com/microsoft-office/excel-2010-convert-number-values-into-time/)